# Using member class template specialization in the class

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a standard complying way of using member class template specialization in the same class?

```
struct S {
    template<typename T> struct Data;
    // Explicit (AKA full) template specialization is not allowed here.
    template<> struct Data<char> {};
    template<> struct Data<int> {};

    Data<char> d1;
    Data<int> d2;
};
```

doesn't work because full specializations of member class template are not allowed inside the class. Some compilers chose to ignore the holy standard in that case and are happy with that code, but some are following the rules.

```
struct S {
    template<typename T> struct Data;

    // Specializations are not defined at this point.
    Data<char> d1;
    Data<int> d2;
};

template<> struct S::Data<char> {};
template<> struct S::Data<int> {};
```

doesn't work either because specializations can't be used before they are defined.

I understand that I can move member class template out of the class, but that's beside the point.

Stupidly enough, I can work around the prohibition on in-class template specialization if I use an additional template parameter just for that reason:

```
struct S {
    template<typename T, typename NotUsed = void> struct Data;
    // Now it's a partial template specialization, which is allowed.
    template<typename NotUsed> struct Data<char, NotUsed> {};
    template<typename NotUsed> struct Data<int, NotUsed> {};

    Data<char> d1;
    Data<int> d2;
};
```

Now it's fine because partial template specialization is allowed inside the class.

Am I missing some way of doing it "the right way" - making specialization outside the class and still be able to use it inside? I am assuming C++17 version of the standard.

Comment: The C++17 standard says, "An explicit specialization may be declared in any scope in which the corresponding primary template may be defined." So why do you think that the "holy standard" says that it shouldn't work?

Comment: In the "Member templates":

"Partial specializations of member template may appear both at class scope and at enclosing namespace scope, but explicit specializations may only appear at enclosing namespace scope."

Comment: I've searched [the C++17 specification](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/), and I cannot find that phrase anywhere. Indeed, the section on [member templates](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.mem) says nothing about partial or explicit specializations.The writing you quoted sounds like it's from some website, rather than the C++ standard.

Comment: It was a quote from cppreference.com. It just magically changed to:
"Partial specializations of member template may appear both at class scope and at enclosing namespace scope. Explicit specializations may only appear at enclosing namespace scope (until C++14) may appear in any scope in which the primary template may appear (since C++17)"
It does look like a compiler bug, then. C++17 removed that constraint, which was present in C++14.

Comment: If by "magically changed," you mean "I changed it", then yes, you're correct.

Comment: Yes, that what I meant.

Comment: I usually use cppreference.com, it will be a lesson to use the original standard, if in doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a standard complying way of using member class template specialization in the same class?

Yes: use a conforming C++17 compiler.

C++17 [directly states](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#2):

> An explicit specialization may be declared in any scope in which the corresponding primary template may be defined

However, [C++14 says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.expl.spec#2):

> An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template.

Your compiler seems to be following the C++14 rules. If explicitly setting it to C++17 (or later) doesn't fix it, then it's a compiler bug.

Comment: Yes, looks like a compiler bug, C++17 should allow that.